# How to stop processes from going into the page file

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

I have a server, and windows vista, 64-bit, 4gb ram. Sometimes the server randomly drops into the page file, and disconnects everyone who was online. Only after I click the cmd.exe window does it comes back out. How do I mark a program as not eligible for the page file?

If this is relevant, I'm using a Minecraft server with the following command line arguments:

```
java -server -Xmx256M -Xms256M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -Xnoclassgc -XX:UseSSE=3 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=3 -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Comment: You cannot do this, otherwise everyone would be using it. That's the beauty of Windows, where all software is treated the same way.

Comment: @Randolph: True, but it's not normal for *actively used* processes to get swapped out randomly.

Comment: @grawity - Yes it is (as a preemptive backing store) but it's odd that it'd also drop out of main memory.  What else is running on this thing?

Comment: It's not random. Obviously something else is taking priority, so @Shinrai's question is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your choices include:

- Buy more RAM so that available memory exceeds total memory required by all running programs.
- Run fewer other programs and services so that total memory requirements are less than available memory
- Increase the CPU priority of the process (task manager, processes, right-click). But this is just a guess - I don't know if a higher CPU priority really reduces the chances of being paged-out when memory is low and subsequently experiencing page-faults.
- Try the standard JVM settings for minecraft server
- Identify what other processes are using large amounts of memory
- Ask Notch why page-faults cause connections to be dropped.

Comment: Right, found the problem, but it was unrelated and had to do with an issue with cmd suspending the program and not the pagefile as I thought(suspending the program naturally led it into the page file).